# jquery keyup misses a shift+> key event if I'm going really fast

Tags: jquery

The follow jquery code moves the value of an input element over to an output element whenever I type in >:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $("#input");
  var output = $('output[name="output"]')[0];
  input.keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 190 && event.shiftKey == true) {// 190 = key code
      output.value = input.val();
    }
  });
});
```

If I'm really going fast, however, the event handler misses a > or two, even though it is captured properly in the input box. Is there a flaw in my code?

Comment: Hmmm, not seeing it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jDrEp/). Browser specific?

Comment: Odd ... I get the same behavior there in Chrome. IE9 doesn't even work.

Comment: According to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5), IE9 doesn't support the output tag.

Comment: Got it on IE9. I can still replicate the same "missed" behavior using two input boxes and `output.val(input.val());`

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't reproduce your exact error, but I've a feeling that what you're seeing is the lag between the time you enter the '>' character and the time your event handler executes. I'm using 2 input boxes, type="text", and the following JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input = $("#input"),
        output = $('#output');
    input.keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 190 && event.shiftKey == true) {// 190 = key code
            output.val(input.val());
        }
    });
});
```

When I enter characters really quickly, I'll sometimes see the output box get the last '>' character plus a couple extra keystrokes. The keystrokes can even be backspaces that erase the last '>'.

Seems to me that instead of simply pulling input.val(), you want to pull the value of the input until the last '>' character, using something like the following:

```
input.keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 190 && event.shiftKey == true) {// 190 = key code
        var val = input.val(),
            lastIndex = val.lastIndexOf('>');
        output.val(val.substr(0, lastIndex+1));
    }
});
```

And here's some docs on lastIndexOf, including a workaround for browsers that don't have it natively:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the combination **shift + enter** on **jQuery 3.3.1**.

In the end the problem seemed to be the **order of keyup events**. When pressing shift + enter you can either release the enter key first (in this case everything works as expected) or release the shift key first (in this case the keyup event had no shift key).
For me, this was the reason, why this problem seemed to only happen when typing realy fast.

The **solution** was to use **keypress instead of keyup**, because when using keypress the order of releasing the keys doesn't matter. If you release the shift key first, it will result in a **keyup event without shift** but in a **keypress event with shift**.